# How do I test JS prototypes (non-modules) in Mocha/Chai?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I want to set up tests for the project I'm building. In the examples I can find, they all say including the relevant code to test is done by a require statement: `require('foo');`. However my project isn't built in modules, but in ES6 classes that are then translated to ES5 prototypes.

I'm wondering how to include the file/s?

So for instance the ES6 class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    // do things
  }
}
```

Translates roughly to:

```
// ES5 compatible code is here (_classCallCheck etc).
var Foo = (function () {    
  function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);

   // do things
  }
}
```

And I'd like to know how to include it in my test file:

```
var expect   = require('chai').expect;
// how to require or whatever else here?

describe('Foo', function() {
  it('creates an Foo object', function() {
    var foo = new Foo({});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use module, you can just create a simple html page for your test like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>your tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="vendor/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"><p><a href=".">Index</a></p></div>
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="fixtures"></div>
  <script src="vendor/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/chai.js"></script>
  <script src="your_files.js"></script>
  <script src="your_files_test.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.run();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this, you don't need to require something in your test file.

If you want more information : [article](http://blog.codeship.com/mocha-js-chai-sinon-frontend-javascript-code-testing-tutorial/)

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks, you sent me in the right direction. I'm using Grunt also, so with [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-javascript-with-phantomjs--net-28243) along with the [grunt-mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/jdcataldo/grunt-mocha-phantomjs) plugin I was able to achieved what I want very easily.